# Quelle expression est correcte: "de quoi" ou "de qu'est-ce que"

Tags: grammaire, registre-familier

Est-ce que c'est possible de dire "De qu'est ce que vous vous souvenez?" ? Au lieu de dire "De quoi vous vous souvenez?" La question avec "quoi" me semble un peu familier...

Answer (score 5):

Il faut se rappeler des deux façons principales de formuler une question : inversion de la phrase verbale principale v. emploi de "est-ce que". Pour les comparer de façon plus précise :

> De quoi vous souvenez-vous ?
>
> De quoi est-ce que vous vous souvenez ?

Toutes les deux sont possibles. Mais étant donné que le deuxième est correct on voit que le choix proposé ci-dessus :

> De qu'est-ce-que vous vous souvenez ?

... n'est qu'une altération non viable. La raison : après une préposition, le pronom "que" se transforme en "quoi".

> <strike>À que</strike> → À quoi
>
> <strike>Pour que</strike> ? → Pour quoi (À ne pas confondre avec "Pour que vous soyez ..." etc.)
>
> <strike>Avec que</strike> → Avec quoi
>
> <strike>De que</strike> → De quoi

Ceci est une règle grammaticale qui s'applique aux deux cas. (La formulation "De que vous souvenez-vous" serait rejetée pour la même raison.) Ce n'est pas question de formalité ou de familiarité.

---

N.B. Si vous voudriez en savoir plus, vous pourriez commencer par lire l'article sur le [cas grammatical](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cas_grammatical), ce qui explique l'alternance entre plusieurs formes de ce qu'on considère comme étant un seul mot :

> *Que* voulez-vous ? ("que" comme objet direct de verbe transitif)
>
> De *quoi* traitez-vous ? ("que" comme objet de préposition)
>
> Vous *me* visez ? ("me" comme objet direct)
>
> Vous parlez à *moi* ? ("me" comme objet de préposition)

Comment: Très bonne réponse - je ne connaissais pas cette règle. J'upvote.

Answer (score 1):

> De qu'est ce que vous vous souvenez?

n'est pas correct, et ne s'entend pas non plus.

> De quoi vous souvenez-vous?

est mieux.

> De quoi vous vous souvenez?

est possible aussi, avec la bonne intonation pour que ce soit une question.

> De quoi est-ce que vous vous souvenez?

est aussi possible, très courant, peut-être la forme la plus courante, mais un registre en dessous de *De quoi vous souvenez-vous?*.

*Quoi* est effectivement familier employé seul, mais pas après une préposition. La dernière forme, sans inversion, est familière à nouveau, mais uniquement parce qu'il n'y a pas inversion.

Si vous voulez vraiment éviter ce *quoi*, il faudrait dire, par exemple:

> Quels sont vos souvenirs de cet événement?

Ou quelque chose de similaire.

Comment: Je me permets de rectifier les formulations qui peuvent induire en erreur. Rollback si tu soutiens vraiment le point de vue original, mais je doute que personne d'autre le soutienne.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - non, c'est bon, c'est une amélioration nette de la réponse, on garde.